# Unable to interpolate an array with one more than one item into another array using %W

Tags: ruby

```
foo = %w[a b]
# => ["a", "b"]
bar = %W[bla baz #{foo}]
# => ["bla", "baz", "[\"a\", \"b\"]"]
```

In the above example, as you can see a and b are wrapped around escape strings, is there a way I can get `["bla", "baz", "a", "b"]`

Comment: `%w[bla baz] + foo` should do the trick right?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @maxpleaner I ended up doing it, but then I was curious about what was causing this and if there is a way to get it working

Comment: @spickermann ["bla", "baz", "a", "b"]

Comment: The interpolation is _string_ interpolation, i.e. you get the result of `foo.to_s`.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You ask, "...is their a way...?". There are many ways, one of which is to just write out the desired array, `["bla", "baz", "a", "b"]`. Presumably you want to know if, given specified Ruby objects, the desired result can be obtained using only specified Ruby methods, operators and keywords. You need to spell out that condition. For example, do you mean that only `%w` and `%W` are to be used?